# How to replace characters, inside specific tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, replace

I need to replace characters inside specific tag using javascript when page loads. I have a big list of characters to be replaced. so it will be fast and should work with major browsers. 
example:-

```
<p> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog </p>
```

will need to looks like

```
<p> h=f t)ujh lk.,h ghy tfbm' bhjf ghy {>ht Frt </p>
```

Thanks!

Comment: If this is some kind of encryption you may have better options available if you explain your need. Also, what have you tried so far, and what happened (or didn't work)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `<p>` an ID and you're on your way:

```
<p id='p1'>content...</p>
```

Javascript:

```
var text = document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML;
text = text.replace("c","x");
...
document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = text;
```

**EDIT**

To target all `<p>`s, do as you said:

```
var allPs = document.getElementsByTagName("P");
var text;

for(i=0;i<allPs.length;i++) {
  text = allPs[i].innerHTML;
  text = text.replace("c","x");
  allPs[i].innerHTML = text;
}
```

You may have to run a `while` loop over the `.replace()`  method, since calling it once will only do a single replacement (i.e. only 1 "c" will be replaced).

Comment: i need to target all <p> tags using Get 'getElementsBytagname' or whatever.

Comment: Not if you add the `g` flag to the regex in the replace. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions and chain multiple replace's together:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var string = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML;
    var replacedString = string.replace(/somespecialchar/gi, "replaceWith").replace(/someotherspecialchar/gi, "replaceWith").replace(/anotherchar/gi, "replaceWith");
    document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML = replacedString;
}
```

Comment: this isn't working for me and it's hard to process my list to this, manner. It's like this text = text.replace(/,/g, "￦");
text = text.replace(/\./g, "�");
text = text.replace(/\\(/g, "￫");

Comment: Ah! You are using non-utf-8 standard characters!